# where is the add web reference in bot function Azure?

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, botframework, web-reference

I want to add a **web reference in my azure function bot project**, using Visual Studio or in the Azure portal; but am unable to determine how to in either case.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: no thank you, the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Functions Bot resource in Azure, go to Build > Download Bot source code. Then follow these instructions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much, you save me

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
Right click on the project -> Add -> Connected Service -> Choose

Comment: i work with bot function in portal azure, and they don't accept the right click on the project

Comment: @Meed095 , working from Azure portal with an Azure function may not be a good idea if you want a code that is a bit complex

Comment: @NicolasR , is there any methods for export my code in azure portal to Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Can't remember as I avoid Azure Function Bot. If it is like web app bot, there may be a button to download the zip of the sources from Azure Portal